# Methane Sensor electrochemical reaction

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

When using a methane sensor a voltage is applied and much like electrolysis if the voltage is above the decomposition potential a reaction happens. Flammable gasses like methane are easily oxidized and thus produce an anodic current. But what is the cathodic current reaction in a methane sensor in air? what is being reduced?

Comment: Is the CO2 reduced to CO carbon monoxide? Can the methane be oxidised to Methanol in the presence of water?

Comment: CH4 + 2O2 --> CO2 + 2 H2O is this the full redox eqn?

Comment: I’ve heard aqueous based (typically acidic) electrolytes produce hazardous substances. But what are they? This was what they used in the 60s iirc